# Problem with the function addChild in php with xml

Tags: php, xml

I am trying do develop a little web app with xml php but some problems occurs. I use some tutorials to understand what i am doing but nothing about the problem that i meet. I want to create a new xml file for a new user with some characteristics (name, email, password, role). You will see in the code i use addChild to add these items in my xml but it generate an xml without the name and just the password and the other it does something very strange.

There is my code :

```
if(count($errors) == 0) {
      $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<user></user>');
      $xml->addChild('password', md5($password));
      $xml->addChild('email', $email);
      $xml->addChild('role', $role);
      $xml->asXML('users/'. $username .'.xml');
      header('Location: login.php');
      die;
 }
```

and this is the new xml generate without a name :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<user><password>d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e</password><email/><role/></user>
```

So the strange thing are the tags `<email/>` and `<role/>`.
So can someone help me ? I just spend 3 hours trying to find a solution XD

Comment: i think the $email and role are empty that why you have empty xml

Comment: can you print $email and $role to see if there is something inside

Answer (score 0):

Apparently - but we can not see this part of code - $email and $role are empty. So empty tags `<email/>` and `<role/>` are generated.

Answer (score 0):

As i said , the **$email** and **$role** are empty , so you can update your code this way :

```
if(count($errors) == 0) {
        $email  = isset($email)? $email : " ";
        $role  = isset($role)? $role : " ";
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<user></user>');
        $xml->addChild('password', md5($password));
        $xml->addChild('email', $email);
        $xml->addChild('role', $role);
        $xml->asXML('users/'. $username .'.xml');
        header('Location: login.php');
        die;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I try it but nothing change but let me send you the whole code :

```
<?php
$errors = array();
if (isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $username = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z]/', '', $_POST['username']);
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $role = $_POST['role'];

    if (file_exists('users/' . $username . '.xml')) {
        $errors[] = 'Username already exists';
    }
    if ($email = '') {
        $errors[] = 'Email is blank';
    }
    if ($username = '') {
        $errors[] = 'Username is blank';
    }
    if ($role = '') {
        $errors[] = 'Role is blank';
    }
    if($password = ''){
        $errors[] = 'Password is blanck';
    }
    if(count($errors) == 0) {
        $xml = new SimpleXMLElement('<user></user>');
        $xml->addChild('password', md5($password));
        $xml->addChild('email', $email);
        $xml->addChild('role', $role);
        $xml->asXML('users/'. $username .'.xml');
        header('Location: login.php');
        die;
    }
}


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Resgister</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Register</h1>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php
        if(count($errors) > 0){
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($errors as $e){
                echo '<li>' . $e . '</li>';
            }
            echo '</ul>';
        }
        ?>
        <p>Username <input type="text" name="username" size="20"></p>
        <p>Email <input type="email" name="email" size="20"></p>
        <p>Password <input type="password" name="password" size="20"></p>
        <p>Role <input type="text" name="role"></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name="login" value="Login"></p>
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

So after that i don't know.

Comment: In your code `$email = ''` is setting the email to be blank - you want `$email == ''` - the same with any other lines like this.

Comment: Ok thank you i didn't notice that because for me its was not a setting but just a condition for the if. Ok now i will know it. Thank you !